# Conditional statements in Hot 18 card game

Tags: python, game, playing-cards

How can I write this shorter (while keeping the same functionality and outputs to console)?

```
def review():
    v1 = value_of_current_cards(hand_one)
    v2 = value_of_current_cards(hand_two)
    v3 = value_of_current_cards(hand_three)
    vd = value_of_current_cards(hand_dealer)
    if number_of_hands > 0:
        print ""
        print "Recap of that round"
        if v1 < 18:
            print ""
            print "First hand: You stayed on %s" % (v1)
            if vd > 18:
                print "*You won on First Hand*" "  (Dealer busted with %s)" % (vd)
            elif vd < 18:
                print "            Dealer stayed on %s" % (vd)
                if vd > v1:
                    print "-You lost on First Hand-" " (Dealer was closer to 18)"
                elif vd < v1:
                    print "*You won on First Hand*" " (You were closer to 18 than dealer)"
                elif vd == v1:
                    print "*You tied on First Hand*" " (You and dealer both had %s)" % (vd)
        elif v1 == 18:
            print ""
            print "First hand: You HIT HOT 18!"
            if v1 > vd:
                print "*You won on First Hand*" "  (Dealer only had %s)" % (vd)
            elif v1 == vd:
                print "*You tied on First Hand*" "  (You and dealer both had %s)" % (vd)
            elif v1 < vd:
                print "*You won on First Hand*" "  (Dealer busted with %s)" % (vd)
        elif v1 > 18:
            print ""
            print "-You lost on First Hand- " "(You had %s, so you went over 18)" % (v1)
        if number_of_hands > 1:
            if v2 < 18:
                print ""
                print "Second hand: You stayed on %s" % (v2)
                if vd > 18:
                    print "*You won on Second Hand*" "   (Dealer busted with %s)" % (vd)
                elif vd < 18:
                    print "             Dealer stayed on %s" % (vd)
                    if vd > v2:
                        print "-You lost on Second Hand-" " (Dealer was closer to 18)"
                    elif vd < v2:
                        print "*You won on Second Hand*" " (You were closer to 18 than dealer)"
                    elif vd == v2:
                        print "*You tied on Second Hand*" " (You and dealer both had %s)" % (vd)
            elif v2 == 18:
                print ""
                print "Second hand: You HIT HOT 18!"
                if v2 > vd:
                    print "*You won on Second Hand*" "  (Dealer only had %s)" % (vd)
                elif v2 == vd:
                    print "*You tied on Second Hand*" "  (You and dealer both had %s)" % (vd)
                elif v2 < vd:
                    print "*You won on Second Hand*" "  (Dealer busted with %s)" % (vd)
            elif v2 > 18:
                print ""
                print "-You lost on Second Hand-" " (You had %s, so you went over 18)" % (v2)
            if number_of_hands > 2:
                if v3 < 18:
                    print ""
                    print "Third hand: You stayed on %s" % (v3)
                    if vd > 18:
                        print "*You won on First Hand*" "    (Dealer busted with %s)" % (vd)
                    elif vd < 18:
                        print "            Dealer stayed on %s" % (vd)
                        if vd > v3:
                            print "-You lost on Third Hand-" " (Dealer was closer to 18)"
                        elif vd < v3:
                            print "*You won on Third Hand*" " (You were closer to 18 than dealer)"
                        elif vd == v3:
                            print "*You tied on Third Hand*" " (You and dealer both had %s)" % (vd)
                elif v3 == 18:
                    print ""
                    print "Third hand: You HIT HOT 18!"
                    if v3 > vd:
                        print "*You won on Third Hand*" "  (Dealer only had %s)" % (vd)
                    elif v3 == vd:
                        print "*You tied on Third Hand*" "  (You and dealer both had %s)" % (vd)
                    elif v3 < vd:
                        print "*You won on Third Hand*" "  (Dealer busted with %s)" % (vd)
                elif v3 > 18:
                    print ""
                    print "-You lost on Third Hand-" " (You had %s, so you went over 18)" % (v3)
```

Comment: You forgot to handle the case `v1 < 18 and vd == 18`

Comment: This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rearrangement of the `if` statements avoids repetition of `print` statements:

```
print 
print "Recap of that round"
print
if v1 < 18:
    print "First hand: You stayed on %s" % (v1)
    if vd < 18:
        print "            Dealer stayed on %s" % (vd)
elif v1 == 18:
    print "First hand: You HIT HOT 18!"

if v1 > 18:
    print "-You lost on First Hand- " "(You had %s, so you went over 18)" % (v1)
elif v1 < vd <= 18:
    print "-You lost on First Hand-" " (Dealer was closer to 18)"
elif v1 == vd:
    print "*You tied on First Hand*" "  (You and dealer both had %s)" % (vd)
else:
    print "*You won on First Hand*",
    if vd > 18:
        print "  (Dealer busted with %s)" % (vd)
    elif v1 == 18:
        print "  (Dealer only had %s)" % (vd)
    else:
        print " (You were closer to 18 than dealer)"
```

Then, use string formatting to insert "First hand" from a variable.

You could use a loop like this to call a function that prints the review of a single round:

```
rounds = (("First hand", hand_one),
          ("Second hand", hand_two),
          ("Third hand", hand_three))
for name, hand in rounds[:number_of_hands]:
    review_round(name, hand, hand_dealer)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can/shuold extract repeating code, e.g. into into functions (see my example)

example:

```
def evaluate_hand(value_of_hand, hand_no, hand_of_dealer):
    """
    Evalutates  ....

    @param value_of_hand the value for the current hand.
    @param hand_no the number of the hand. Have to be a value of the interval [1,4]
    @param hand_of_dealer contains the value of the dealers hand
    """
    hand_to_str_dispatcher = {1: "First hand", 2: "Second hand", 3: "Thrid hand", 4: "Fourth hand"}
    print "Recap of that round"
    if value_of_hand < 18:
        print ""
        print "{0}: You stayed on {1}".format(hand_to_str_dispatcher[hand_no],value_of_hand)
        if hand_of_dealer > 18:
            print "*You won on First Hand*" "  (Dealer busted with {0})".format(hand_of_dealer)
        elif hand_of_dealer < 18:
            print "            Dealer stayed on {0}".format(hand_of_dealer)
            if hand_of_dealer > value_of_hand:
                print "-You lost on {0}-  (Dealer was closer to 18)".format(hand_to_str_dispatcher[hand_no])
            elif hand_of_dealer < value_of_hand:
                print "*You won on {0}* (You were closer to 18 than dealer)".format(hand_to_str_dispatcher[hand_no])

            elif hand_of_dealer == value_of_hand:
                    print "*You tied on {0}* (You and dealer both had {1})".format(hand_to_str_dispatcher[hand_no], hand_of_dealer)
    # .....
    # adjust the subsequent code accordingly

def recap_round():
    hand_of_dealer = 10
    v1 = 19
    v2 = 2
    v3 = 20
    v4 = 22
    hands = [v1, v2, v3, v4]
    print "Recap of that round"
    for i in range(0, len(hands)):
        evaluate_hand(hands[i], i + 1, hand_of_dealer)
```

Run the `recap_round` function in order to see how the example works.
If you try to understand the used concepts and methods you probably get a better
idea how to structure you're code in the future.